# Maven still doesn't run after setting environment variables

Tags: maven

here is what I have set in User Variables to run maven..

**JAVA_HOME**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
```

**M2**

```
%M2_HOME%\bin
```

**M2_HOME**

```
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4
```

**MAVEN_OPTS**

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

**PATH**

```
%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;
```

but still a `mvn --version` command gives my error. 
I followed the steps in their own website and still getting the error.
Do you see anything wrong with what I posted above?

Comment: This isn't a maven question, it's a simple matter of Windows path management. 'mvn' is just 'mvn.bat' from the bin dir. There's nothing maven-specific here. Are you sure that PATH is set as you think it is in the command-line windows you are using?

Comment: And if you navigate to `%M2_HOME%\bin` there is a mvn executable or batch file in that directory?

Comment: That's a great question. I have the same problem. It's totally weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you restarted your command line window after PATH set up?

Comment: I did restarted command prompt, computer, brain. still no result.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by restarting the command line tool, for doing this you have to start your CMD as administrator. Right click on CMD icon and select "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 1):

On your place I would try this:

open command prompt (Start - Run - type "cmd")
and type:

```
cd %M2_HOME%\bin
dir
```

make sure you see something like "mvn.exe" or "mvn.bat"

If "cd %M2_HOME%\bin" doesn't work, the something wrong with environment. (Ex: you logged in with different user). Try

```
echo %M2_HOME%
```

in command prompt.

PS:
The better way to check environment is to type "set" in command prompt.